# fasttext - some word vectors returns 0

Tags: r, fasttext

I am a new entry to R and fastText.

I read on fastText website that you should be able to retrieve words vectors for names like "New York" by typing "New_York" but it's not working for me. Actually, there are also other vector that I'm not able to recall properly.

I thought that it could be because of the OS (I work on windows).

```
require(plyr)
require(proxy)
require(ggpubr)
require (jtools)
require(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
require(fastTextR)

london_agg <- read.csv2("londra_latlong2.csv",header=T,sep=",",dec=".",fill = T)

model <- ft_load("fastText/cc.en.300.bin")

london_agg$Name <- as.character(london_agg$Name)
ccc <- ft_word_vectors(model,london_agg$Name)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of your data using `dput()`. As it is, there is nothing here for the community to reproduce the error and help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A word-vector model will only have full-word vectors for a string like `New_York` if the training data had preprocessed the text to create such tokens. I'm not sure if the `cc` FastText models, specifically, have done that – their [distribution page](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) doesn't mention it. (Google's original `GoogleNews` vectors in plain word2vec had used a phrase-combining algorithm to create vectors for a lot of multiword tokens like `New_York`.)

Failing that, a FastText model will also synthesize guess-vectors for other tokens that weren't in the training-data, using substrings of your requested token.

The `cc.en.300.bin` vectors are reported (on same page as above) as only having learned 5-character n-grams, so unknown (out-of-vocabulary with respect to training-tokens) token with fewer than 5 characters couldn't get any vector from FastText.

But those with more characters should get at least junk vectors. (The method for matching n-grams is based on a collision-oblivious hashtable, so even if 5-grams weren't in the training data, there should be some random junk data returned.)

Perhaps there's a bug in the R FastText implementation you're using. Separate from looking up your specific geo-data tokens, could you expand your question with some examples of individual tokens, of different lengths, that either return credible vectors (every dimension non-zero) & absolutely nothing (all zero dimensions)? The pattern of lookup words that return all-zeros might give a further hint as to what, if anything, the problem is.